# Insert into not working on Node.js with oracle Database

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

today i wanna try insert data to my oracle database but the data can't saved to database
here my code

```
async function db () {
return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      console.log("processing")
      connection = await oracle.getConnection(konek);
      var result = await connection.execute(`INSERT INTO MS_PERANGKAT (SERIALNUMBER, SSID) VALUES (:1, :2)`, ['12333', 'Rupadana']);

      connection = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM ms_perangkat");

      resolve(connection)
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err)
    } finally {
      if (connection) {
        try {
          await connection.close();
        } catch(err) {
          reject(err)
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

db().then( async connection => {
  console.log(connection)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Error: ',err)
});
```

Here the output :

```
{
  metaData: [ { name: 'SERIALNUMBER' }, { name: 'SSID' } ],
  rows: [ [ '12333', 'Rupadana' ] ]
}
```

[and here my Oracle Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkRbw.png)

Comment: I agree with Wayan. I just want to comment that the explicit promise you're returning from `db` seems unnecessary. Async functions automatically return promises. If the function returns a value, then that value is used to resolve the promise. If the function throws an error, the promise is rejected with that error. See this series to learn more: https://jsao.io/2017/06/how-to-get-use-and-close-a-db-connection-using-various-async-patterns/

Comment: thank you @DanMcGhan for the Information :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that happens because the query hasn't been committed

here the code:

```
var result = await connection.execute(`INSERT INTO MS_PERANGKAT (SERIALNUMBER, SSID) VALUES (:1, :2)`, ['12333', 'Rupadana'],{autoCommit: true});
```